# Unable to set google api credentials

Tags: c#, api, credentials, google-translate

I am trying to use the google translation api in my application by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), but having some trouble setting up the authorisation.

I created the service account, got the json file, and set it in with

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\Bassie\Documents\.credentials\google-translation-api\My Project-d885ebbbe907.json"
```

After running that command I don't see any output, and I don't see a system environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (is that where it should appear?).

When I try running some basic sample code:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.'

What am I doing wrong?

**update**

even after manually adding the value to system environment variables, I get the same error.

Comment: hey did you ever figure this out? Im dealing with this issue right now, I've tried everything

Comment: @Wizard check the comments on the answer - looks like I just needed to restart the command prompt / PC to get the environment variable to show up

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%
```

If it is not working, then right click on my computer(or This PC) icon, properties, in the advanced tab, click on Environment Variables, add a new variable under system variables.

Then check `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` in command prompt.

Comment: calling `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` just echos the string `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`, but as mentioned in my question I already tried adding this manually and it still didn't work

Comment: echo %WINDIR% should output c:\windows, similarly echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS% should output the path to your json file. Pls check again. Also check for spelling errors.

Comment: did you close and reopen your command prompt window ? I tried and it works and expected. Full path is echoed.

Comment: Thanks nammalvar, you prompted me to restart my computer and it then started working. However it seems that I have to buy a subscription to use the features that I need!