# Unable to add environment variables

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

I have an extremely annoying issue where I am unable to set a new environment variable.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988843/unable-to-set-google-api-credentials), I am simply trying to set up authorisation for an application to use a google API.

I tried setting the variable with

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\Bassie\Documents\.credentials\google-translation-api\My Project-d885ebbbe907.json"
```

But this does nothing.

Then I manually went into system variables and added it, see:

[image]

Yet still, if I call these commands:

```
echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%
```

it just echoes

```
%GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%
```

and calling `set` does not display the variable as being there.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Please help me.

By the way I am using windows 10

Comment: It follows the Unix behavior pretty closely.  The SET command only changed the environment of the command processor, Cmd.exe.  Any program you subsequently start from the Cmd.exe command line will see the added variable.  But not any that were already running or are started another way, like through Explorer or the Run command.  Changing the system variable likewise has no effect on any running process, other than Explorer.  Only programs you subsequently start through Explorer will see the added variable.

Comment: Don't add a quote in the environment variable itself. For example, it's `set "lunch=spam and eggs"`, not `set lunch="spam and eggs"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to drop the '=' and just have a space. Then when you list the environment variable it should show up as var=value.